# When upgrading from Hyperloop to Hyperstack, is "opal_hot_reloader" gem still necessary?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, isomorphic, hyperstack

I am just upgrading a Rails app from Hyperloop to Hyperstack. Is the "opal_hot_reloader" gem obsolete since Hyperstack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes... a version of the hot-loader is built into hyperstack now.

In your `hyperstack.rb` initializer you want:

```
  Hyperstack.configuration do |config|
    ...
    config.import 'hyperstack/hotloader', client_only: true if Rails.env.development?
  end
```

The Procfile (for foreman) looks like this:

```
web:        bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0
hot-loader: bundle exec hyperstack-hotloader -p 25222 -d app/hyperstack
```

assets/javascripts/application.js should end like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require hyperstack-loader
```

The hyperstack loader will (using the initializer) figure out what additional code to add to your assets including the hotloader.

Comment: FYI if you are upgrading I would also just glance at https://github.com/hyperstack-org/hyperstack/blob/edge/install/rails-webpacker.rb to see what the standard install looks like and update your files accordingly